# Animate.css isn't working when adding/removing classes

Tags: jquery, css, syntax, css-animations

For whatever reason my the addClass, removeClass is not working in my hover function. I thought it was a syntax issue but even after I resolved the the issue still remains. Please advise.

Here is the function

```
$(".run").hover(function(){
    //alert("1");
    $(this).addClass("animated infinite");
  }, 
  function(){
    //alert("2");
    $(this).removeClass("animated infinite");
  }
);
```

And here is a link to the function
http://jsfiddle.net/galnova/y50wr52n/9/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because you aren't toggling the `bounce` class.

[**Updated Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/ed8gnL6e/)

```
$(".run").hover(function(){
    $(this).addClass("animated infinite bounce");
  }, 
  function(){
    $(this).removeClass("animated infinite bounce");
  }
);
```

Apparently there are some cross-browser inconsistencies. This fixes it in Chrome. Now it works in all supported browsers.

---

You can avoid JS/jQuery completely and use the following:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/LrvmLukx/)

```
.run:hover {
     -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    -webkit-animation-duration: 1s;
    animation-duration: 1s;
    -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    animation-fill-mode: both;
    -webkit-animation-name: bounce;
    animation-name: bounce;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: center bottom;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
}
```

You might want to use the animation shorthand, though:

[**Example Here**](http://jsfiddle.net/bdg3hwem/)

```
.run:hover {
    -webkit-animation: bounce 1s infinite both;
    animation: bounce 1s infinite both;
    -webkit-transform-origin: center bottom;
    -ms-transform-origin: center bottom;
    transform-origin: center bottom;
}
```